# The steam API 2020

Tags: api, steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm looking to make a hobbie website using the steam API, mostly focusing on the actual products and not really any user info. According to an article by the man behind Steamspy, Valve decided to change their API sometime in 2018, removing a lot of relevant data related to the store.
I went through the steamworks documentation and the closest thing to any specific information about the applications/games were in:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/ISteamApps -
I figured their API must offer more than just a list of all the apps and their ID's, but thus far I have only found some other API:s.

- https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/User:RJackson/StorefrontAPI

Seems to be popular in a lot of threads

- https://steamapi.xpaw.me/#ISteamApps

Some kind of collection of APIs?

- https://github.com/Autarc/steam-store/blob/master/README.md
  Not sure if this is still usable?
- https://steamspy.com/api.php

Question: If I want the name, ID, genre/tags and picture of a game (and potentially price), is really the only way to use these non-valve related API:s? Or have I missed something in Valves own API documentation?

I'm super new to API:s so please forgive my insolence, I did search a ton of threads but seeing as the API changed I'm not sure which answers still are up to date in 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The storefront API is still up-to-date and should give you what you need, mostly.

There is no API for game tags. You have to get the directly from the store pages or from any of the third party API providers if they have them.

> Question: If I want the name, ID, genre/tags and picture of a game (and potentially price), is really the only way to use these non-valve related API:s? Or have I missed something in Valves own API documentation?

No, you have not missed anything. Yes you need to use unoffical APIs. Compared to other gaming stores you still get more data on Steam than anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late reply, this cleared up a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid the last answer is not fully true.
You can get tags as categories or genres through api eg.https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids=306480